# Is there any way to run specific cells of a databricks notebook automatically?

Tags: task, databricks, workflow, jobs

For example, I have a databricks notebook with 5 cells. I want to create a databricks job to run cells 2 and 4, but not 1, 3 and 5. How can I do this?

Is there any way to do it from databricks?

Comment: Maybe a round about way - take a widget that takes cell numbers - convert it to a list in the first cell of the notebook - then manually check if the current cell number is available in that list - if so keep the logic within it or else exit and proceed...Not that easy to maintain - just by adding a cell, the order could get changed...but it is one possible way...

Answer (score 0):

We have the options either for running all the cells above/below the selected the cells but I did not find any method/option to run specific selected cell as you mentioned "cells 2 and 4 but not 1 and 3" so far. I tried selecting those specific cells 2 and 4 to run only but only the last selected cell executed all the time when I was able to select multiple cells.